# switch statement C++ and glut

Tags: c++, switch-statement, keypress, glut

I have this function that says when I press `a` I switch between `GL_LINE` and `GL_FILL`. when I run the program it starts with `GL_FILL` and when I press `a` it switches to `GL_LINE`. However I want it to keep switching between the both when `a` is pressed.

can someone tell me where I am going wrong.

```
void keyPressed (unsigned char key, int x, int y) { 
switch (key){
case 'a':
    bool f = false;
    if(!f){
        glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT,GL_LINE);
        glPolygonMode(GL_BACK, GL_LINE);

    }else{
        //bOutline=false;
        glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT,GL_FILL);
        glPolygonMode(GL_BACK, GL_FILL);
    }
    f=!f;
    break;

}

}
```

Comment: I thought that you couldn't define a variable in a `switch` statement.

Comment: @Derek You can if you introduce scope to the case with braces {}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think you must switch between 2 state that is handled by f , so you need to define f in outer scope or define it as static variable like this

```
static bool f = false;
```

Answer (score 2):

you define the bool `f` inside the function each time it's called, so you should either define it as a global variable, I don't recommend that, or as a static variable:

```
static bool f = false;
```

You could also use `glGet` with the argument `GL_POLYGON_MODE` to find the current mode for the front and back faces, example:

```
GLint polyMode[2];
//returns front and back modes
glGetIntegerv(GL_POLYGON_MODE, polyMode);

switch(polyMode[0]) { 
    case GL_LINE:
        //add code
        break;
    case GL_FILL:
        //add code
        break;
    case GL_POINTS:
        //add code
        break;
}
```

Comment: @aserwin actually, outside the function or as a static variable.

Answer (score 2):

You should define f as a static variable to maintain its value between function calls.
static bool f = false;
or just make it a global variable

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need `f`? Seems to me you want a toggle between two values, so why not something like this:

```
GLint previous[2];
glGetIntegerv( GL_POLYGON_MODE, previous );
glPolygonMode( GL_FRONT, previous[0] == GL_LINE ? GL_FILL : GL_LINE);
glPolygonMode( GL_BACK, previous[1] == GL_LINE ? GL_FILL : GL_LINE);
```